# increase dataset size classification machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, prediction

| Index | Temperature | Humidity | Rainfall | pH | N | P | K | Soil | Crop | Fertilizer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 24.87 | 82.84 | 295.61 | 6.59 | 4.0 | 2.0 | 2.5 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 28.69 | 96.65 | 178.96 | 6.08 | 4.0 | 4.0 | 4.0 | 4 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 20.27 | 81.64 | 270.44 | 5.01 | 4.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 | 6 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 25.07 | 95.02 | 192.90 | 5.55 | 2.0 | 2.1 | 3.5 | 5 | 0 | 5 |
| 4 | 25.04 | 95.90 | 174.80 | 6.18 | 2.0 | 3.9 | 2.1 | 3 | 0 | 6 |

Is there any way to increase the size of data specially in rows with proper values ??

I don't want the random generation of the data it will not end with good accuracy of my Machine learning model.

Actually this is my project on machine learning : to predict the type of fertilizer on the bases of given parameters.

But my professors told to increase the size of my data-set.
I am having the 200 records of this dataset, I want mode 600.

So please help, or just give some reference of i can figure it out!!

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score -1):

As this sounds like a classification problem it is very useful to try and balance the dataset so that all classes have the same number of samples. You can simply do that by oversampling, that means you repeat the classes with fewer samples for that look at [imbalance](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/over_sampling.html).

That documentation also shows you how to use more sophisticated oversampling methods such as ADASYN and SMOTE. I would recommend to try both.